# image not loading in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to prepare a document for printing and i like to load a small logo on it. the image loads fine in Mozilla Firefox and IE but it doesn't load in google chrome. i don't know what the problem is. any suggestions ? 
here is a part of my code:

```
 mywindow.document.write("<table border='solid gray 1px' style='text-align:center'>");
 mywindow.document.write("<tr><td><img src='CSS/images/logosmall.jpg'></img><td><td> <span  style='font-family:Tahoma'>HELLO</span></td></tr>");

 mywindow.document.write("</body></html>");

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
```

Comment: `<img src='CSS/images/logosmall.jpg'></img>` can be `<img src='CSS/images/logosmall.jpg'/>` I am not saying that is the reason for your problem.

Comment: i tried it before but no results. thanks any way.

Comment: there are some issue with your html like img tag and missing closing tag for td. I have update the html please see my answer

Comment: You haven't closed your `<td>` properly after the image in line 2 of your post.

Comment: Also </table> is missing

Comment: as i said it is just a part of my code i have done everything properly. this is just the part where i load the image and the part where i print it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var strHtml  = "<table border='solid gray 1px' style='text-align:center'>";
    strHtml += "<tr><td><img src='CSS/images/logosmall.jpg' /></td><td><span  style='font-family:Tahoma'>HELLO</span></td></tr></table>";
    strHtml += "</body></html>";

  mywindow.document.write(strHtml);
  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close()
```

Comment: I have tried this and its working on Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 m
please take the last edited version of my answer and check your version of chrome

Comment: my version is the same as yours